# Stop cmdlet after X iterations

Tags: powershell

I have a cmdlet that takes pipeline values:

```
1..10 | Test-MyCmdlet
```

I want to limit `Test-MyCmdLet` to only process the first 5 objects (*edit* not by limiting the input piped to it.)

My first solution was to set a counter in the `BEGIN` block, increment that in the `PROCESS` block, and break out of the process block once it reaches a threshold. That seems a little 'hacky' to me.

Is there a better way?

The tl;dr version of how I arrived at this question is:

I have a C# module that defines a cmdlet `Open-View` with the following parameter

```
[Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true)]
public IViewDef[] View {get; set;}
```

where `IViewDef` is a custom type from another assembly. The cmdlet opens windows in a 3rd party app.

`IViewDef` has a property called `Name`

I wanted to make the cmdlet a little more versatile so I changed it to this:

```
[Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipelineByParameterName = true)] // by parameter name
public string[] Name {get; set;} // notice that this is now Name
```

Now I can also call it from the CLI and type my own viewnames.

This introduces a problem tho: it no longer recognizes `IViewDef` objects piped in. I think that is because `ValueFromPipelineByParameterName` expects the parameter name of the input object to be of the same signature, ergo `string[]`.

So I changed it to:

```
[Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipelineByParameterName = true)]
public string Name {get; set;} // no more array
```

That works, *but* there is a reason I originally defined it as an array: I wanted to be able to count the number of views being passed in and stop processing them if their number reaches a threshold. I can now no longer do that. Back to the original question.

Comment: Is your function streaming any objects? I'm not familiar with C# but normally you can use `Select-Object -First X` to stop the stream of your function (assuming the function is returning objects).

Comment: You could definitely do what @SantiagoSquarzon suggests, before piping to your cmdlet. Besides that, I don't have the feeling that your implementation is hacky. To make it more professional, I would add a paramter to your cmdlet to control that threshold. Let it default to 5, but give the user the opportunity to modify it so that he is also aware that this threshold exists. Other cmdlets do the same (like [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7.1) with the `-Depth` parameter)

Comment: Thank you, I think I will go with Thomas' suggestion.

Comment: I think it is important to elaborate on why @SantiagoSquarzon's comment is not applicable to my situation. My question is not about limiting the amount of objects passed, it is about putting a limit *within* the cmdlet. I hope this makes it clearer for future readers.

Comment: @Rno I was actually gonna recommend adding a `Threshold` parameter in your function which is what Thomas recommended in his comment above but since this was extra work I wanted to make sure your function was not streaming any objects :)